# C++ error instantiated from here when using templates

Tags: c++, vxworks

```
template<class Concept> class OMAbstructContainer 
{ 
    friend class OMIterator<Concept> ;

    // ...
};

template<class Concept> class OMStaticArray :
            public OMAbstructContainer<Concept> {
protected:
    Concept *theLink;
    int count;

    void* AllocateMemory(int size);
    bool  ReleaseMemory(void* pMemory);
public:
    // Constructor
    OMStaticArray(int size): count(0) 
    {
        theLink = NULL;
        theLink = (Concept*) this->AllocateMemory(size); 
    }
}; 


template<class Concept> class OMCollection :
    public OMStaticArray<Concept>{
public:
    // Constructor
    OMCollection(int theSize=20):
      OMStaticArray<Concept>(theSize) { 
        size = theSize;
    }

    // Destructor   
    ~OMCollection() { } // The link is delete in ~OMFixed()

    //...
};
```

Now i am using above collection as below

```
class MyVar
{
public :

    // Constructors and destructors:
    MyVar(int Index) { }

    // ...
};

OMCollection<MyVar*> m_pCollVars;
```

When i am runing above code in vxworks6.8 C++ compiler  i am getting following error

```
error: instantiated from 'OMStaticArray<Concept>::OMStaticArray(int) [with Concept = MyVar*]'
```

I am facing lot of errors like above. The code used to compile fine using VxWorks 5.5 compiler.

I have following error
error: instantiated from 'OMCollection::OMCollection(int) [with Concept = MyVar*]'

I am getting at following line:
OMCollection(int theSize =DEFAULT_START_SIZE):
      OMStaticArray(theSize) { 
        size = theSize;
    }

I have no clue why i am facing with these errors, can any one help me how this can be fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: The part pasted is just pointing to where the error comes from, not what the actual error is.

Comment: These are not errors, lines like that is a description of the instantiations that lead to an error. The actual error message should be somewhere above or below lines like that.

Comment: You just added another non-error to the question. Show us an error that does *not* begin with "instantiated from". And mark the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Or just paste all the error lines in one code block - for those code blocks you automatically get scrollbars if there is too much content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no visible error from your question. One problematic thing I see is that you are instantiating `OMStaticArray<Concept>` where `Concept = MyVar*`; so,

```
Concept *theLink; ==> MyVar **theLink;
```

Now your `AllocateMemory()` returns `void*`;

Are you sure you want to convert `void*` into `MyVar**` ? Due to C-style casting you are not noticing that, but that statement is not convincing.

Comment: If he wants a dynamically allocated buffer of pointers, he needs to have a pointer to the buffer somewhere - i.e. a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Georg, that's true but IMO less likely; that's why I am asking him, if that's really what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

You are using IBM Rhapsody, right? The containers Rhapsody provides are "reference containers" but the template parameter should be the class you what the containers to contain pointers to, not a pointer to class.

Eg

```
class Foo {...};

OMColloction< Foo > myFooCollection;
```

Is what you want.

NB: all the Rhapsody containers must be instantiated with a class never a fundamental type, as 0 is a valid value for a fund type but the end-of-container marker for the reference containers.